# My app works locally but on Heroku I'm just getting the React logo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

When I run my app locally it works just fine. I deployed my app on Heroku and the build was successful without any errors. However, whenever I open the app, I just get the revolving React icon page that you get when you first create a react app. I'm getting nothing in the console and the Heroku log is giving me back status 200 so I'm not sure what's going on.

I notice it has something to do with my build folder because when I delete the app returns "Not Found".

I believe its in my server.js file.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const path = require("path");

var app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}





if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){  
    app.use("*", function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build/index.html"));
    })
}

app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
    console.log(`server listening on localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I just tried copying over from an app that I did successfully launch on heroku. I'm fairly new to coding so I don't even know what half of it means. If someone could help me out, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you locally visit `client/build/index.html` do you see the default react app? Can you add your package.json to your question? Problem could be that your `build` folder is located at a different place or Heroku is not doing `npm build` or a similar command in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you are using `create-react-app` and you're not serving the `/build` folder. You can easily add an express server to do it.

First, install the express module:

```
npm install express --save
```

And the add a `server.js` file that will serve your `/build/index.html` on all requests:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: His code looks fine to me. Can't tell without knowing his folder structure but I think it is pretty safe to assume he has a clients folder. Here is another question that also puts the build files in client/build: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60647361/error-when-deploying-heroku-app-cannot-get

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didnt have a build script in my package.json